# using rdfs:subclassOf as an annotation property

Tags: annotations, owl, ontology, protege, rdfs

I want to use rdfs:subclassOf as an annotation property without being included in the class hierarchy, how I can do that in protege?

Comment: impossible, `rdfs:subClassOf` semantics is hard-coded for obvious reason - just use your own property - it would be better to explain what you want with an example maybe?

Comment: It is questionable whether it makes sense to use subClassOf, which has semantic meaning, as an annotation property since annotation properties have no semantic meaning and thus has no affect on reasoning. If you want to use subClassOf without any affect on reasoning, you probably better of using [SKOS](https://www.dataversity.net/introduction-to-skos/#:~:text=SKOS%2C%20which%20stands%20for%20Simple,out%20in%20any%20RDF%20syntax.) broader/narrower.

Answer (score 1):

Using `rdfs:subClassOf`, or any of the terms defined in the rdf, rdfs or owl namespaces, for a purpose different from the ones defined in the specs is likely to create unexpected situations, and might not achieve what you expect.

For example, things may work out differently depending on the syntax you use. In RDF/XML, parsing of rdfs:subClassOf will always create subclass axioms; in non RDF based syntaxes, this might work as you expect (the property is defined as a rdf:Property, so other parsers might just treat it as an annotation property).

You'd have inconsistent results in your own uses, I think - and certainly it would be difficult for the ontology to be reused by other parties, who might not be aware of any format limitations.

Best choice would be to define your own annotation property for your purposes, I think.